# MS Word Automation using python

Tags: python, python-docx

I have ms word document and I want to apply the following setting automatically using python

Font type = Trebuchet MS

Font Size = 11

Table and Appendices font Size = 10

Line spacing = multiple of 1.15

Space before paragraph = 0

Space after paragraph = 0

Paragraph should be Justified

Number should be aligned to the bottom right corner of document

Text in the table should be Justified

Insert footer and header automatically

This is my code so far but it does not apply the changes to ms word document

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.shared import Length

path = 'C:\\Users\\Gaston\\Documents\\Words\\test.docx'


doc = Document(path)



style = doc.styles['Normal']

font = style.font  
font.name = 'Trebuchet MS'
font.size = Pt(11)  

paragraph = doc.add_paragraph()
paragraph_format = paragraph.paragraph_format
paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.JUSTIFY
paragraph_format.right_indent = Inches(1)
paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(0)
paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)
paragraph_format.line_spacing = Length(1.15)

doc.save(path)
```

Comment: You add a new paragraph. Do you have text there to watch the new formatting? Try: paragraph = doc.add_paragraph("some text here"). Please, check, if the file was updated by saving? Check file date and time.

Comment: yes I have the text on that document